# Add language to non admin account - Windows 10 with Admin

Tags: windows, windows-10, language, input-languages

I want to install a language on a non-admin account on the system.
While on my admin account I can install Text-to-speech and all other features, on the non-admin account I can only install display languages in the language menu. Other features are not an option.

How can I install all features on the non-admin account?
I do have admin rights.

Comment: Settings is a UWP application.  UWP application permissions cannot be elevated.  It sounds like what you want to do requires an Administrator. Why can't an Administrator installed the required languages for the non-Administrator accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if only one step is enough but these two solved it:

1. Install the language on the admin account
2. On the second account with elevated PowerShell Install -Language
3. Install the language on the user account (via setting). Windows only displayed the standard feature for input-language. But when installing it made all features available for the account.